Why does a square inside a circle inside a square inside a circle inside a square have 1/2 of the dimension of the outside sqare?
Draw a square A with sides a of size 10.
Draw a circle B inside square A that has the maximum diameter, i.e. 10.
Draw a square C inside circle B, with all 4 corners on the circle. Its diagonal is 10 (i.e. is the circle diameter). By pythagoras, its sides c can be calculated as 2c^2 = 10^2, i.e. 5 sqrt(2), i.e. approx 7.07.
Draw a circle D inside square C that has the maximum diameter. It has diameter 5 sqrt(2).
Draw a square E inside circle D, with all 4 corners on the circle. Its diagonal is 5 sqrt(2). Its sides e can be calculated as 2c^2 = (5 sqrt(2))^2; 2c^2 = 50; c^2 = 25; c=5, i.e. half the dimension of a.
This pattern repeats. It's not intuitive to me that circling-squaring-circling-squaring is equivalent to (x * 1/2). Is there a more direct way to express the relationship between a and e? What's going on that causes this?
Thanks!
Update - ah, writing helped to clarify this. Thinking only about the triangles leads fairly trivially to a^2 = 4e^2, which reduces to a=2e. The function of the circles is to force the relationship of the squares such that the diagonal of a given square is equivalent to the side of its grandparent.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
